# How to display visitor's city AND state in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, api, geolocation, google-places-api

I am trying to customize content on my WordPress website to display the user's city and state (e.g. Miami, FL).

Here is what I have so far:

```
function visitorcity_function() {
 $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
 $url = "http://geoip.nekoapi.icu/api/" . $ip;
 $json = wp_remote_fopen($url);
 $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
 $city = print_r($data['city'], true);
 $result = $city;
 return $result; }

 add_shortcode('visitorcity', 'visitorcity_function');

 add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop' );
 add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

It displays the city just fine when I use the shortcode. I'm trying to modify it to also display the state abbreviation but I can't find available data points for the http://geoip.nekoapi.icu API
anywhere.

Can anyone help? Or perhaps point me to a way to do this using Google's geo API? Either would be most appreciated!

Thanks!

Cynthia

Comment: It doesn't appear that the API you're using displays the state at all.

Comment: Sigh...that would explain it then :)

Comment: If you're using WooCommerce, you could use the `WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip`

Comment: I wound up using geolocation-db.com's API and was able to get it working